# Filter entries in a file based on columns in another file

Tags: perl, unix, awk, filter, rows

is there a way to filter entries in a file based on entries on another file? (preferably in unix)

For example file 1 and 2 has 50 entries (rows) and 10 columns. Based on the last 5 columns i would like to use only unique entries in file1. i.e. entries exist in file1 but not in file2 (based on the last 5 column).

i tried diff but it only seems to work for 1 column entries.

Comment: It is quite probable that it will be possible with either `grep` or `awk`, for example. For that, we need some sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

This Perl script seems to do what you ask.

It builds a hash from `file2` using the last five fields in each record as a key, and then does the same for `file1`, printing the record if `file2` contained the same key

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my %file2;

open my $fh, '<', 'file2.txt';
while (<$fh>) {
  next unless /\S/;
  my @fields = split;
  my @key = @fields[-5..-1];
  ++$file2{"@key"};
}

open $fh, '<', 'file1.txt';
while (<$fh>) {
  if (/\S/) {
    my @fields = split;
    my @key = @fields[-5..-1];
    print unless $file2{"@key"};
  }
  else {
    print;
  }
}

close $fh;
```